# Local PC development w/ ElasticSearch - High Memory Usage makes my desktop unusable

Tags: elasticsearch, development, workflow

I´m new to Magento and I´m trying to install Magento locally in my work desktop to test my code development before pushing it back to the Integration Branch.

I already tried with the ["Local Development Setup"](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/setup/first-time-setup.html) and ["Docker Cloud Development"](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-development.html) Instruction. In both setups my machine becomes unresponsive. With the Local Development Setup I could verify that the culprit of the unresponsiveness is the ElasticSearch application using 10GB of RAM in 6 or more different PID´s.

I´m using Ubuntu under WSL 2.0 on a Windows 10 machine with 16GB RAM, Intel Core i5-2500 (Yeah, the hardware does not help much...)

So a couple of questions:

- Is there anyway yo make this work on a local machine?
- Is testing expected to be done at a dedicated server on Magento?
- Is there anyway to configure Elastic Search to use less memory or simply not use it on Magento 2.4?

I´m kindda lost on how to accomplish this, so if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be really grateful!

Thanks!

Comment: Try reducing the JVM heap size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421232/elastic-search-high-memory-consumption

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I configured it to a lower value than the answered on the link, Confgured it to 512m (-Xms512m and -Xmx512m).